# Regex to match substring of a string

Tags: regex, substring

I have an enumeration that I use as fixed parameter values to a program and I use regex to sanitize the user input.

I want the user to be able to enter a partial match to one of the values and accept that value and not other values.

For example if the enumeration is:

```
end
end now
start
swarm
condition
```

and the user entered

```
s
st
sta
etc...
```

it will be ok because it is part of start;
but if the user entered

```
ending
```

it will not be ok because its not part of any of the other words.

I know I can specify each permutation in a group `(s|st|sta|star|start)` and it will do the work, but doing this for around 12 different values seems very hard to maintain and "ugly'...

Is there an easier way to match a fixed values or sub of those fixed values?

I'm **not** searching for something that is specific to one engine/language (for example java code..)

Comment: I wouldn't do that in regex only - you need to split the user input into words anyway and check each against the commands anyway. Some regex engines do provide a "starts with" query (like Python's `re.match()`), in others you can prepend a `^` to the regex to force it to match at the start of a string, but in any case, you need to do some programmatic work beyond the regex itself.

Comment: `s(t(a(rt?)?)?)?)?` does what you ask more succinctly. Some languages have libraries which will do this for you but there can hardly be a language-agnostic way to run that code.

Comment: `st?a?r?t?` would apparently do the trick

Comment: @Vivick sure, if `srt` is valid.

Comment: I searched for something more elegant, maybe an operator that I missed. But it seems the only option is to maybe accept the input by some general regex and add specific validation in code (as post processing)

Answer (score -1):

Regex is not the correct tool for this job.

Just find the length of the user's input (call it N), then loop through your valid values and see if the first N characters of that value matches the input.

If only one item matches, you've got yourself a result! If more than one matches, you'll need more letters from the user to identify the correct one. And if none match, it's invalid.

Comment: Doing this in code is very easy ( check if the enum values starts with the value passed and return if find a match). Since I'm validating my input, (for length, char set and matching of values...) it actually feels like something that should be easily done by regex...

Comment: You *can* do it in regex, but similarly you *can* use a sledgehammer to insert a screw. Doesn't mean it's the best tool for the job.